# QLocale::formattedDataSize in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I do not see [this API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#formattedDataSize) available in `QML` ([locale](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-locale.html)).

Is the only way to use it is to call it from `C++` part?

Comment: Most likely, it does not exist, create a class in c ++ that has a method that uses that function and expose the class to QML.